# Accessing User.currentUser from Boot.scala onAboutToShutdownSession

Tags: lift

I'm working on an eShop project in Lift right now. For convenience reasons every user that visits the shop is assigned a persistent ProtoUser entry in Mapper. This entry is flagged temporary. 
I now have to delete the DB-entry on session termination using onAboutToShutdownSession

Obviously i don't have access to User.currentUser there, as i'm outside a session. (?) I still have the LiftSession Reference in my function.

The question is: How can I access the currentUser (or even currentUserId) SessionVar from either the context of LiftSession or Boot.scala

Thanks for your answers!

Andreas

Answer (score 1):

You can't access a SessionVar outside a session.

If you've constructed a function during the servicing of a request, you can do something like:

```
val id = User.currentUserId.get
val f: () => Unit = () => {
   id.foreach{realId => deleteFromDatabase(realId)
}
```

Because the id val is captured within the scope of a request and f closes over scope, the value of User.currentUserId will be captured and the function will be able to delete the user from the database.

Comment: I'm very honoured to be answered by the BDFL himself, yet this was not entirely the point of my question. Nevertheless I found the error, wich was entirely on my side of the keyboard :-( Thanks very much anyway!